# How to order by calculated column in mysql

Tags: mysql

It is very slow to order by calculated column. Like this one:

```
select
  `users`.`id`,
  `username`,
  `about_me`,
(
  select
    count(*)
  from
    `interests`
  inner join `users_interests` on `interests`.`id` = `users_interests`.`interest_id`
  where
    `users`.`id` = `users_interests`.`user_id`
    and `interest_id` in (1, 2, 4) --this is ids of interests which authenticated user has chosen
) as `interests_count`
from
  `users`
order by
  `interests_count` desc
```

So in this query i am ordering users By interests which is best suiting authenticated user. And it is very slow in large data tables. Any ideas what will be alternative and much faster solution. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

**Users Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`roles_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
`username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`about_me` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `users_username_unique` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
KEY `users_roles_id_foreign` (`roles_id`),
CONSTRAINT `users_roles_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`roles_id`) REFERENCES 
`user_roles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50102 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Interests Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `interests` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`interest_category_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `interests_interest_category_id_foreign` (`interest_category_id`),
CONSTRAINT `interests_interest_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY 
(`interest_category_id`) REFERENCES `interests_categories` (`id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Pivot table between Users and Interests**

```
CREATE TABLE `users_interests` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `interest_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_interests_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `users_interests_interest_id_foreign` (`interest_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_interests_interest_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`interest_id`) REFERENCES `interests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `users_interests_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251552 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Aliases are gonna blow your mind

Comment: Hmm, I think you maybe can join directly, use aggregation and get rid of the subquery. Maybe that's faster. For further investigation [edit] the question and add the relevant `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements (if any) and the explain plan. Also add sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: I have Added `CREATE TABLE` statements

Answer (score 0):

Without test data it's difficult to know if this would be faster than your current query, but you might find the use of a Common Table Expression (a.k.a. WITH clause) to be helpful here:

```
with cteCount AS (select ui.`user_id`,
                         count(*) as `interests_count`
                    from `interests` i
                    inner join `users_interests` ui
                      on i.`id` = ui.`interest_id`
                    where ui.`interest_id` in (1, 2, 4))
select u.`id`,
       `username`,
       `about_me`,
       cc.`interests_count`
from `users` u
inner join cteCount cc
  on cc.`user_id` = u.`id`
order by
  cc.`interests_count` desc
```

The performance of this query will be affected by the presence or absence of indexes on the appropriate columns. Just glancing at it I'd say you should have the following indexes available:

```
interests
  Index 1: id

users_interests
  Index 1: interest_id

users
  Index 1: id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this have same results as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to directly join and aggregate.

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.username,
       u.about_me,
       count(ui.interest_id) interests_count
       FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN users_interests ui
                      ON ui.user_id = u.id
                         AND ui.interest_id IN (1, 2, 4)
       GROUP BY u.id,
                u.username,
                u.about_me;
```

Additionally create an index supporting the aggregation.

```
CREATE INDEX users_id_username_about_me
             ON users
                (id,
                 username,
                 about_me);
```